# Можно ли символы использовать для арифметических операций

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>

int main() {
char x='*';
///
}
```

Могу ли я использовать *x* для выполнения арифметических операций ?

Comment: Если вы хотите написать выражение, в котором знаки операции это текущие значения переменных, то нет (в С++ это невозможно). Но, если вы хотите получать результат вычисления подобных выражений, выполняемых вычислителем на другом языке, то принципиальных проблем нет (только учтите, что это будет *очень медленно* (по сравнению с native expression execution))

Comment: @avp, понял, спасибо

Comment: Приведите пример что вы хотите сделать?
В этом примере в переменную x помещаете ASCII-код символа звёздочка.

Comment: @GUN_ter к примеру 
cout<<5x2;
И что бы выполнилась нужная операция